# How to configure Ivy's lock strategy in Sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

I need to configure Ivy [lock strategy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/lock-strategies.html) in sbt build.

I tried to place `externalIvySettings(baseDirectory(_ / "ivysettings.xml"))` in `Build.scala`

ivysettings.xml:

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver="default"/>
  <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-public.xml"/>
  <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-shared.xml"/>
  <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-local.xml"/>
  <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-main-chain.xml"/>
  <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-default-chain.xml"/>
  <lock-strategies>no-lock</lock-strategies>
</ivysettings>
```

But in this case sbt cannot resolve dependencies(I suppose because resolvers are shielded by resolvers from ivysettings).

How can I configure lock strategy in `Build.scala` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending some time around I found the solution. I copy-pasted ivyConfiguration from defaultSettings and replaced GlobalLock parameter with None (I need to disable lock):

```
ivyConfiguration <<= (externalResolvers, ivyPaths, offline, checksums, appConfiguration, target, streams) map { (rs, paths, off, check, app, t, s) =>
        val resCacheDir = t / "resolution-cache"
        new InlineIvyConfiguration(paths, rs, Nil, Nil, off, None, check, Some(resCacheDir), s.log)
      }
```

It looks like a workaround for me, but it works. Now there is no ivy lock.
Please help me improve the solution if you know how, since I'm new to sbt.