# SBT disable ivy lock

Tags: scala, ant, sbt, ivy, sbt-assembly

I'm new at scala and sbt so my question may sound silly. 
So I have complex play/scala project. Compilation can take 15-25mins (I'm running only one sbt instance).

I've used this https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-optimizer plugin to recognize the root of the issue.

I found that ivy lock takes lots of time:

[image]

So I've googled about ivy and found [some info about ivy locks.](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/lock-strategies.html)
Then I found similar issues at SO [How to configure Ivy's lock strategy in Sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194604/how-to-configure-ivys-lock-strategy-in-sbt) but this doesn't help me (build time is the same).

So I want to speed up project build time, so I suppose I need some how change ivy lock strategy. How I can do this?

Or maybe you have some ideas how to speed up build?

Comment: what is taking so long in the build? 25 mins sounds too much

Comment: @Java Dude How many dependencies do you have in your project? 25min is an abnormal compilation time, even with large codenbases, assuming that you have a decent machine.

Comment: I have good machine the latest i7, 32gb DDR4 RAM, SSD etc. So it's not hardware problem,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [coursier](https://github.com/coursier/coursier) plugin. It removes the ivy lock and can download your artifacts in parallel.